# Android FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, eclipse, exception

I'm new to this android programming and do not know where to start with my question nor do I know what I should post here. Here I have the log showed in red in Eclipse.
When I start the app, and type in something and click on Send, the app will crash and this log I will get in Eclipse. I'm following this tutorial: [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Hope someone can help me out

```
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.hello.world/com.example.hello.world.DisplayMessageActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2160)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-10 21:40:45.783: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onCreate` method of `DisplayMessageActivity`, call this as the first line:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

In fact, your tutorial states this (comment is added by me, though...):

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // This is important!
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }
}
```

Comment: O I see, nice thank you and it worked like a charm, I will mark your answer as accepted answer in 11 minutes